# Where to get SIM cards in Tokyo, Japan?

Tags: japan, cellphones, internet

I am traveling to Tokyo next month and will either need a SIM card or a pocket wifi for when i am in Tokyo. I thought about just using the free wifi but i've been told that it is hard to find in Tokyo. So i was wondering if anyone had any recommendations? When i was looking around for a few rental companies i found these three and were wondering if anyone has rented from these companies before?

https://www.genkimobile.com

https://www.econnectjapan.com

https://ninjawifi.com

If anyone has any information that would be great. Or if you recommend any other rental companies please let me know!!

Comment: Not enough for an answer probably, but I used japan-rail-pass.com (they sell SIMs in addition to rail passes, and also pocket wifi although I did not use that) the 2nd time I went to Japan and Sakura Mobile the first time. Service on both was good, but Sakura was less convenient (had to receive the SIM at my hotel and mail it back). I am not affiliated with either, just stating what worked for me.

Comment: I just purchased a SIM today through B-mobile, which is a respected budget carrier in Japan. The price is much better than Sakura. They have several options for delivery or pick-up.

Comment: How long will you stay? There are lot of options, at airports or big electronic stores like Bic Camera or Yodobashi Camera

Answer (score 1):

Rentals made sense back when Japanese phone networks were largely incompatible with the rest of the world, but those days are long gone.  Free WiFi is now available in some places, but you usually can't rely on it being available when you most need it, and there are often annoying registration hoops that either require understanding Japanese, having a local number or both.

Your best bet is to **buy a local SIM card**, and you can do this easily and cost-effectively right at the airport on arrival:

[Where to get data-only SIM in Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53595/where-to-get-data-only-sim-in-japan)

[Prepaid SIM with voice & data at Haneda Airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72883/prepaid-sim-with-voice-data-at-haneda-airport/73005#73005)

Note that voice & data SIMs are more expensive and limited than data-only SIMs, so pick accordingly.